# Testing searchview in android - Instrumentation testing

Tags: android, android-instrumentation, expresso

I have a searchview in my action bar, where I can press on search button in action bar, write some text, then click on the search button on softkeyboard and then it should display the list of results in recycler view.

I want to test this to see if the results in recyclerview contains the same word as I searched for (The result is list of movies).

For example, if I search for "love" and the result is all movies with names which contains word "love" in it like "P.S. I love you"

I am trying this:

```
@Test
    public void testSearchToolbar() throws Exception {
        Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation();
        onView(withId(R.id.action_search)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(android.support.design.R.id.search_src_text)).perform(typeText("Seven Samurai"));
        inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH);
        onData(withId(R.id.movie_title)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }
```

I see that the text is getting typed in searchview but beyond that test fails.

Can someone help me with this

Comment: I think you should get the instrumentation using `InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation()` ?

Comment: I have imported this : import android.app.Instrumentation;
import android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry

Comment: That's fine but AFAIK you should not use new Instrumentation()

Comment: okay. I have changed that to what you suggested. But how can I test my scenario. I still dont see the search button getting clicked on keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

In 2022 I do this for my case:

```
        onView(withId(R.id.action_search))
            .perform(click())
        onView(withId(R.id.searchView))
            .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
        onView(isAssignableFrom(EditText::class.java))
            .perform(typeText(query), pressKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
        Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(resId))
                .check(ViewAssertions.matches(CustomMatchers().recyclerViewSizeMatch(count)))
```

Comment: Interesting solution. You really helped me!
Kinda sad that google hasn't provided more convenient way to test and perform acts on searchview.